# Starting position of coil in a generator

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I came across a few a.c. generator diagrams and I noticed for all of them the starting position of coil is vertical(area vector parallel to B vector)
Is there a reason for this? And if you can start in a horizontal position, would the emf graph look the same? (By start I mean when t=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the starting position of the coil that you quote, the flux linkage with the coil is $$N\Phi=BAN\cos \omega t.$$ Therefore the emf is $$\mathscr E =-\frac{d(N\Phi)}{dt} = BAN\omega \sin\omega t.$$ Here are two reasons for choosing this starting position. (a) It's usual to express the flux through an area in terms of the cosine of the angle between the magnetic field and the normal to the area. (b) It's convenient not to have a minus sign in the equation for emf (as you would if the coil had its normal at right angles to the field at time $t=0$).

[There is something of the tongue-in-cheek about (b)... (i) Since the emf is alternating, the presence or absence of a minus sign is usually of no interest at all. (ii) What does it even *mean* to say that the emf is positive or negative? If a load resistance were connected across the coil, which way round through the coil would the current have to be for the emf to be counted as positive? This question does have an answer, but perhaps it needs some thought.]

Comment: is "wt"  in the emf formula  change in angle? Otherwise it would mean emf is induced when my starting position is horizontal (wt=90) even though I haven't started turning the coil, w=0 and t=0.

Comment: $\omega t$ is the angle between the normal to the coil and the magnetic field direction. $\omega t=0$ when the coil is in the starting position that you specified in your question. So when $\omega t= \pi/2$, that is when $t= \pi/2 \omega$, the emf is a maximum because $\sin \omega t$ is a maximum (exactly 1). If $\omega=0$ the emf equation tells you that $\mathscr E=0$ whatever the angle of there coil!